# Стандартное значение при привзяке

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

Делаю привязку. Например нужно привязать Фон прямоугольника к параметру фона в объекте. Всё хорошо, но как задать своё значение по умолчанию?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:APIButton}">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:APIButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="border" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" RadiusX="{Binding RadiusX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:APIButton}}}" RadiusY="{Binding RadiusY, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:APIButton}}}"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},TargetNullValue=APIButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" HorizontalContentAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue=Center, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">

                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding MouseOverFill, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding MouseOverStroke, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="label" Value="{Binding MouseOverForeground, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding PressedFill, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding PressedStroke, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="label" Value="{Binding PressedForeground, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding NoEnabledFill, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding NoEnabledStroke, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="label" Value="{Binding NoEnabledForeground, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: покажите свой код

Comment: Добавил в пост коды

Comment: А вы не могли бы заменить простыню на минимальный пример, демонстрирующий проблему?

Comment: Дело не в проблеме в коде, а в вопросе с помощью чего в XAML(предпочтительнее)  или в коде реализовать стандартное значение для CustomControl. Например дефолтный фон кнопки, или дефолтное название. например что бы я в МэйнФорме выбирал новую мою кнопку, выносил на форму, и она уже по умолчанию была например с серым фоном, белым текстом, синим при выделении и тд, а не просто прозрачная кнопка.

Comment: @BwehaaFox У вас сейчас "стандартные значения" в XAML, стиль задан для всех кнопок вашего типа. Вас что-то не устраивает в этом решении? Что-то не работает? На первый взгляд всё правильно и канонично.

Comment: @Discord В стиле указаны привязки к параметрам, которые в коде указаны с помощью Get-Set и взаимодействует с DependencyProperty.

Вот тут я делаю привязку стандартных элементов Fill к Background
Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
И соответственно когда я её делаю, в стиле она ставится как Null(В редакторе отображается как привязанная и неактивное окно выбора заполнения обведенное желтой рамкой, и выбрано "Без заполнения"). В итоге в редакторе стиля она выглядит полностью прозрачно, а уже в проекте при её создании нужно задавать все нужные цвета, так как они по умолчанию Null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение через код.

Для своих DependencyProperty записал так:

`public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedFillProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FillPressed), typeof(Brush), typeof(APIButton),new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));`

Для стандартного например Background пришлось сделать переопределение:

`public new static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Background), typeof(Brush), typeof(APIButton), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));`

Если есть вариант через Xaml, буду благодарен.